# How to get crash reports from store app with HockeyApp integration

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, hockeyapp

I have created an App on www.hockeyapp.net manually which created an AppID for me. Also, I have integrated the HockeyApp sdk in my Android app and included the AppId i got from the manual creation on the HockeyApp. I have tried uploading the apk to the hockey app in beta mode and downloaded from the page provided for app distribution which worked fine.

Now I want to upload my Android app to the store. I want to know will the app directly send crash reports to HockeyApp as I have included the AppID and sdk in it while creating the .apk or should I first upload it to HockeyApp and then download it from there and then upload to the store?

I am confused on how it works with Store apps. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have integrated the HockeyApp SDK and signed the apk, you can now upload it to the store. You will automatically get the crash reports in the HockeyApp crashes section. You just have to integrate the SDK and test it. If it works fine in your test, then it will work fine on store too.

Comment: @hello world let me know if you need more help. And accept the answer if you are satisfied :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer . I just test the way you said and let you know

Comment: I signed the apk again and uploaded it to my app directly through my pc. but the crash is not showing on the hockey app.Iam I doing something wrong?

Comment: Make sure that your key is valid and haven't any spaces on start and end, Also make sure that you have follow their guidelines properly. I f it is working fine on unsigned apk then it should work fine on signed apk too.

Comment: - Added app id to android app
- Created new apk
- Added new apk to my phone
but it did not show any report. Then I uploaded the same apk to hockey app and then it showed the crash

Comment: Do I have to add the apk to the store as well as the hockey app?

Comment: I think i got why it wasnt working. I had removed the previous apk I uploaded to Hockey app and just tried testing without uploading any apk to it. Once I added an apk there, all crashes started showing.